# how to make sure my activity runs exactly 10 minutes and then either exits or switch to another activity

Tags: android

Sir, i want to incorporate handler method with the following code:

```
class MTest extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
b1.setOnClickListener(this);
b2.setOnClickListener(this);

}// oncreate method closes here
```

//And then:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.b1:
    ....
    break;
case R.id.b2:
   ....
   break;
}
```

}

i am unable to figure out which part of the above code to be written in run of runnable. and which part in oncreate method..

on writting b1.setonClicklistner(this); inside run i am getting an error as:

The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new Runnable(){})

i m all confused...please help
thank you in advance.. 
Regards

Comment: I would do it with a CountdownTimer

Comment: hmm...i look into it sir..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule a runnable to fire after 10 minutes, and then do whatever you want inside run(). In onCreate(), setup the handler and runnable:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do your code here
            //for example, if you want to finish current activity
            //do this:
            finish();
        }
    };

    //schedule it after 10 mins
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10 * 60 * 1000);

    //set your buttons here as well
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);

    //rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Dear Melquiades...Regards sir..i definitely try and reply soon if all worked out.

Comment: sir i m confused ...is this all has to be inside oncreate method

Comment: Yes, create handler and runnable in onCreate(), inside run() method place your code of whatever you want to do after 10mins, then call postDelayed().

Comment: class MTest extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...
     Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
     Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
     b1.setOnClickListener(this);
     b2.setOnClickListener(this);
     ...

     }

     //And then:

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.b1:
        ....
        break;
     case R.id.b2:
       ....
       break;
       }   
     }

Comment: Now how to incorporate "handler" with the code mentioned above?
 
being a beginner, i am unable to understand which part of the code(mentioned above) is to be written inside run method of runnable, which part is to be written inside oncreate..i am unable to figure it out how the handler method to be incorporated with this code..please help.

Comment: DISCRIPTION above mentioned code: its buttons onclicklistener.... checking which button was clicked (lets say out of 4 buttons) using switch case and perform the particular action based upon the clicked  button.

Comment: Sir, i have placed  button1.setonClickListner(this); inside Run method of Runnable..but it throws an error :                                                                The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new Runnable(){})...

Comment: Please update your original post with all the above, it's difficult to read it here.

Comment: sir, i have updated the code..please have a look..i hope my problem is clear to you..

Comment: sir, it worked perfectly fine....i really appreciate the support..thank you for teaching handler function...regards..take care

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with this desired behavior.
You should take into consideration the following:
- why would the user stay in your app for 10 min?
- what if the app is not in front? or even running?
- what if the screen is off?

You can definitely do what Melquiades suggested but I don't understand why....

Comment: Dear MarkySmarky , its a test for a student(my small kid)...and only 10 minutes i want it to run and store the results...i definitely keep in mind the considerations..Regards